# what's the relation between deformation theory and moduli space theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, moduli-space

Ex., Is the dimension of moduli space  computed from deformation theory, or the construction of it from deformation theory? In complex geometry or algebraic geometry,  or  probably it holds in more categories

Comment: Deformation theory is essentially the local theory of moduli spaces, in the same way that analysis is the local theory of manifolds.

Comment: Yes, but i want more precise relation, for example  the answer to above two questions

Comment: It depends on the problem. But the basic idea is that "first-order deformations" (the linear term when you do a power series expansion of an "honest" deformation") form a vector space that is usually a cohomology group, and this is the tangent space to the moduli space. For example, the tangent space to the Hilbert scheme at a projective scheme $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ is $T_{[X]} Hilb = H^0(X,N_{X/\mathbb P^n})$. Another common example is the moduli space of curves, where one has $T_{[C]} \mathcal M_g = H^1(C,T_C)$.

Comment: How about the construction of fine or coarse moduli space? Is related to the deformation theory?

Comment: I believe there are approaches that involve using deformation theory to construct moduli spaces as algebraic spaces, which one then shows are actually projective schemes by constructing an ample line bundle. But this rough summary is about the extent of my knowledge on the subject.

Comment: It seems that we still have an obstruction living in the second cohomology, otherwise the dim of moduli space of curves would be dimH^1(C, Tc). the dimension should be computed  from Riemann-Roch.Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: Why do you think there is an obstruction? Using Serre duality and that for curves $T_C \cong \omega_C^\vee$, we get $h^1(C,T_C) = h^0(C,\omega_C \otimes T_C^\vee) = h^0(C,\omega_C^{\otimes 2}) = 2(2g - 2) - g + 1 = 3g - 3$ (where per Riemann-Roch the last $h^0$ is really $h^0 - h^1$ with $h^1 = 0$).